# Need a simple RegEx to find a number in a single word

Tags: regex

I've got the following url route and i'm wanting to make sure that a segment of the route will only accept numbers. as such, i can provide some regex which checks the word.

/page/{currentPage}

so.. can someone give me a regex which matches when the word is a number (any int) greater than 0 (ie. 1 <-> int.max).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

Problems with other answers:

```
/([1-9][0-9]*)/ // Will match -1 and foo1bar
#[1-9]+# // Will not match 10, same problems as the first
[1-9] // Will only match one digit, same problems as first
```

Comment: [0-9]+ will actually match 10, but will also match 0, which was unwanted.

Answer (score 7):

If you want it greater than 0, use this regex:

```
/([1-9][0-9]*)/
```

This'll work as long as the number doesn't have leading zeros (like '03').

However, I recommend just using a simple `[0-9]+` regex, and validating the number in your actual site code.

Answer (score 1):

This one would address your specific problem. This expression

```
/\/page\/(0*[1-9][0-9]*)/ or "Perl-compatible" /\/page\/(0*[1-9]\d*)/
```

should capture any non-zero number, even 0-filled. And because it doesn't even *look* for a sign, `-` after the slash will not fit the pattern.

The problem that I have with eyelidlessness' expression is that, likely you do not already have the number isolated so that `^` and `$` would work. You're going to have to do some work *to isolate* it. But a general solution would not be to assume that the number is all that a string contains, as below.

```
/(^|[^0-9-])(0*[1-9][0-9]*)([^0-9]|$)/
```

And the two tail-end groups, you could replace with *word boundary* marks (`\b`), if the RE language had those. Failing that you would put them into non-capturing groups, if the language had them, or even lookarounds if it had those--but it would more likely have word boundaries before lookarounds.

Full *Perl-compatible* version:

```
/(?<![\d-])(0*[1-9]\d*)\b/
```

I chose a negative lookbehind instead of a word boundary, because '-' is not a word-character, and so -1 will have a "word boundary" between the '-' and the '1'. And a negative lookbehind will match the beginning of the string--there just can't be a digit character or '-' in front.

You could say that the zero-width assumption `^` is just one of the cases that satisfies the zero-width assumption `(?<![\d-])`.

Comment: "likely you do not already have the number isolated" - except Pure.Krome specifically said that it is available as the variable 'currentPage'. And also said: "i also do not need to check for the word 'page' or the '/' character, etc."

Comment: correct eyelidlessness. I'm not sure why people can't understand what i said? :)

it's pretty simple (my question) : how do i check if a word is a number greater than zero. that's it.

anyways .. question has been answered :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string testString = @"/page/100";
string pageNumber = Regex.Match(testString, "/page/([1-9][0-9]*)").Groups[1].Value;
```

If not matched pageNumber will be ""

Answer (score 0):

While Jeremy's regex isn't perfect (should be tested in context, against leading characters and such), his advice is good: go for a generic, simple regex (eg. if you must use it in Apache's mod_rewrite) but by any means, handle the final redirect in server's code (if you can) and do a real check of parameter's validity there.

Otherwise, I would improve Jeremy's expression with bounds: `/\b([1-9][0-9]*)$/`
Of course, a regex cannot provide a check against *any* max int, at best you can control the number of digits: `/\b([1-9][0-9]{0,2})$/` for example.

Comment: i'm happy that the number provided COULD be larger than an int.max.
I really just wanted to check that the string is a number greater than zero and is a number. if it's larger than int.max ... meh. i'm not too worried.

Answer (score 0):

This will match any string such that, if it contains `/page/`, it *must* be followed by a number, not consisting of *only* zeros.

```
^(?!.*?/page/([0-9]*[^0-9/]|0*/))
```

`(?! )` is a negative look-ahead. It will match an empty string, only if it's contained pattern does *not* match from the current position.

Comment: cheers .. but i do not want to check for the existence of the word 'page'. i just need to make sure the string i have is a number (using regex).