# Regex only returns value when anchor is provided

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using the following pattern to match numbers in a string.  I know there is only one number in a given string I'm trying to match.

```
var str = "Store # 100";
var regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]*");
```

When I call `regex.Match.Value`, this returns an empty string.  However, if I change it to:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]*$");
```

It does return the value I wanted.  What gives?

Comment: Does playing with the Multiline settings make any difference?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs nah, both `SINGLELINE` and `MULTILINE` produce the same results

Comment: `var regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]*").IsMatch(str);` returns true. voting for not reproducable.

Comment: Problem is you're getting lots of empty matches, one for each character and then '100' at the end. With just $ you'd get one empty match at the end. The one regex that works apparently is @"[1-9][0-9]*$"...

Comment: @bokibeg ahhh interesting, can you explain why this is generating empty matches?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out, I don't know why "\d\d*" works perfectly... this will be a long night.

Comment: @bokibeg wow no kidding, it does work...well I suppose I'll use that for now as it accomplishes I want it to without that limiting anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

The problem with `[0-9]*` or let's make it simpler: `\d*` is that `*` makes it **optional** so it will also result in zero-length match for every character before the '100'.

To rectify this you could use `\d\d*`, this will cause at least one mandatory digit before the rest and clear out zero-length matches.

Edit: The dollar version, e.g. `\d*$` will only work if your number is at the end of the input string.

[More information here!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html)

Aaaaand [One more link for yet even more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252626/need-a-simple-regex-to-find-a-number-in-a-single-word) (what a time to be alive).

Comment: Better to use `+` instead of `*`, whereas `*` means "0 or more times", `+` means "1 or more times", which is more in line with the goal here. In other words, `new Regex("[0-9]+")` or `new Regex(@"\d+")`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> The quantifiers *, +, and {n,m} and their lazy counterparts never
>   repeat after an empty match when the minimum number of captures has
>   been found. This rule prevents quantifiers from entering infinite
>   loops on empty subexpression matches when the maximum number of
>   possible group captures is infinite or near infinite.

So, as the minimum number of captures is zero, the `[0-9]*` pattern returns so many NULLs. And `[0-9]+` will capture `100` without any problems.